# Distinguish exceptions and determine what to log

Tags: .net, logging, nlog, exception-logging

Is there any known approach for logging different information depending on the exception type?

The idea would be only log relevant information per exception type.
eg: known exceptions/business logic exceptions don't need a stack trace logged, since they are "expected"

Basically what I'm asking is if there are any known practices while logging exceptions to make the log as helpful as possible w/o any trash.

Answer (score 3):

You can filter in the `<rules>`, e.g.

```
<rules>
    <logger name="*" writeTo="file1">
        <filters>
            <when condition="'${exception:format=Type}' == 'ExpectedException' " action="LogFinal" />
            <when condition="true" action="Ignore" />

        </filters>
    </logger>
    <logger name="*" writeTo="file2">
        <filters>
            <when condition="'${exception:format=Type}' == 'OtherException' " action="LogFinal" />
            <when condition="true" action="Ignore" />

        </filters>
    </logger>    
</rules>
```

See [when filter](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/When-filter) and [conditions](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Conditions) docs.